# VS2010 intellisense would fade if press Ctrl key

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

On my VS2010, when intellisense is showing, and if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, the whole intellisense would be dimmed out and very hard to see until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is released.

This is very annoying as I remaped my up down arrow keys to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> using autohotkey to save my RSI.

Does anybody know an option/workaround to either configure keybinding to navigate intellisense or make it not dim out?

Comment: Feature, not a bug. Complain to MS.

Comment: Heh, I could do nothing when ctrl key is pressed, the intellisense is still there, but just with high transparency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/), then you are in luck as it has a reg option to disable the Ctrl key fade behavior in Visual Studio.

Reg value named "ListboxFlags" at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Whole Tomato\Visual Assist X\VANet10

Or the value with 0x10 (value is 0 by default, so in that case, just set the value to 0x10).